# What is an efficient way to find the LCM (Least Common Multiple) of $26$ distinct numbers from $1$ to $52$ inclusive?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I want to be able (using a computer), to multiply $26$ integer numbers (from $1$ to $52$) but prevent the product from growing very large because it seems to maybe be causing some problems in the computer language I am using.  So I want to know if there is a good way to limit the product so that all of the factors can still be divided into the resulting product without any remainder.  Shrinking the example down to only $4$ numbers for simplicity (but remember the real world scenario will have $26$ numbers to multiply together), suppose we had $2, 3, 5$, and $50$.  Simply multiplying them together would give $2*3*5*50=1500$.  However, we don't need $1500$ because $150$ will suffice.  So is there a way (ideally "on the fly") to get to $150$ as I see the numbers in order ($2,3,5,50$)?  I would get $2*3=6$ then I would get $6*5=30$ but then how to get from $30$ to $150$?  Maybe just keep a list of all factors (and quantities of them) seen so far so when I get to $2*3*5=30$, then I see $50$, since $50$ is $2*5*5$ and I have already seen $2*5$ once, just add in the 2nd $5$ to get $30*5=150$?

Also in reality, the partial products will be very large, not small like in this simplified example.

I will add an example shortly of $26$ numbers that need to be multiplied such that the product is minimal (or near minimal such as $2$x minimal).

The algorithm I am looking for can be multiple pass, meaning an initial scan of the numbers can be made and remove factors such as $13$ when there is also a factor of $26$ or $39$ already.  The 2nd pass could me more along the lines of a LCM algorithm but since I am using an interpreted language, I would like it to be fast running.

A real example of $26$ numbers needing to be multiplied (but with LCM) is:

$3,4,5,7,9,10,11,12,14,15,18,20,21,22,24,26,28,30,33,35,36,39,40,42,45,52$

I wonder what the LCM of all these are.  Notice terms like $24$ and $36$ would just drop out since we already have $12$.  Also $22$ and $33$ would drop out since we have $11$ already.  I am not sure but I think the LCM would be $3*4*5*7*11*3*13*14 = 2,522,520$

Comment: Well lcm(a,b,c.....z) = lcm(a,lcm(b,lcm(c,..... lcm(x,lcm(y,z))))))))))))))))).  So if you have a method for lcm just apply it 26 times.

Comment: I thought about that already but it might be too slow cuz I have to call it hundreds of thousands of times in my simulation program so I wanted a more efficient version, possibly using multiple passes over the input numbers and using multiple subalgorithms.

Comment: You need to think about feasibility before efficiency: your worst case is going to be the lcm of maximal prime powers less than 52: $2^5 \times 3^3 \times 5^2 \times 7^2 \times 11 \times 13 \times \ldots$. Is that going to be too large for your programming language?

Comment: Actually I made a silly error and it is working now.

Comment: Good for you: it you want to do it really fast: precompute the prime factorisations of the numbers between 1 and 52 and compute the lcm of a sequence of such numbers by calculating the maximum exponent you need for each prime.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but fun puzzle.

For each prime, it will be included in your results with a multiplicity equal to it's max for any given number in the list.
For example, if your list contains no multiple of 7's except 49, then 7 will have a power of 2.
This code counts primes in such a way. It's C# and not a math language, but I'm sure you can translate.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    public class Program
    {
        private const int Max = 1000;
        private static readonly int[] Primes = PrimesLessThan(Max);

        private static int[] PrimesLessThan(int max)
        {
            var composite = new BitArray(max);
            var maxSqrRt = (int) Math.Sqrt(max);
            for (var i = 2; i < maxSqrRt; i++)
            {
                if (composite[i])
                {
                    continue;
                }

                for (var j = i * i; j < max; j += i)
                {
                    composite[j] = true;
                }
            }

            var values = new List<int> {2};
            for (var i = 3; i < max; i += 2)
            {
                if (!composite[i])
                {
                    values.Add(i);
                }
            }

            return values.ToArray();
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", Primes.Select(x => x.ToString())));
            Console.Write(Lcm(3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 18, 20, 21, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 33, 35, 36, 39, 40, 42, 45, 52));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static int Lcm(params int[] args)
        {
            var primesCount = Primes.Length;
            var slots = new int[primesCount];
            foreach (var i in args)
            {
                var number = i;
                for (var j = 0; j < primesCount && number > 1; j++)
                {
                    var prime = Primes[j];
                    var count = 0;
                    while (number % prime == 0)
                    {
                        number /= prime;
                        count++;
                    }

                    if (count > slots[j])
                    {
                        slots[j] = count;
                    }
                }
            }

            var result = 1;
            for (var i = 0; i < primesCount; i++)
            {
                result *= (int)Math.Pow(Primes[i], slots[i]);
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

The result is 360360, which you've gotten wrong by including 14 in your multiplication, you need to remove it and add 1 to the power for 2. For ease of use you'd want this: 2^3 * 3^2 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13